# Tensorflow: Proper queue closing between sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two graphs (one for training and one for evaluation), which use the same inference network, but different input data. The inputs are created by reading binary data files. The graphs are run one after another and in seperate sessions. It actually seems to work, but I can't get rid of a warning that occurs everytime I close a session:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x7fb7ac082980 Compute status: Cancelled: Enqueue operation was cancelled
 [[Node: input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueMany[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer, input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:286] Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt
```

My question is, how do I properly close all queues and threads in order to avoid the warning. I wrote a little example, which shows what I'm doing and hopefully lets you reproduce my problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import struct
import numpy as np


file_name = 'test.bin'

def write_binary_file():
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(20):
            # image = np.ones([3, 3])*i
            image = np.zeros([3, 3])
            image[:, 0] = i
            image = image.astype('uint8')
            for u in range(3):
                for v in range(3):
                    f.write('%s' % struct.pack('B', image[u, v]))

# write binary file
write_binary_file()
print "size of one entry"
print 9
print "size of file"
print 20*9

# GRAPH DEFINITION
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file_name])

reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(header_bytes=0, record_bytes=9)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

value_uint8 = tf.reshape(tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8), [3, 3])

# FIRST session
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
for i in range(5):
    key_v, value_uint8_v = sess.run([key, value_uint8])
    print key_v
    print value_uint8_v

coord.request_stop() # *HERE* the warning is thrown
coord.join(threads, stop_grace_period_secs=5)
sess.close()

# SECOND session
sess2 = tf.Session()
coord2 = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads2 = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess2, coord=coord2)
for i in range(5):
    key_v, value_uint8_v = sess2.run([key, value_uint8])
    print key_v
    print value_uint8_v

coord2.request_stop()
coord2.join(threads2, stop_grace_period_secs=5)
sess2.close()
```

Do you know how to fix the warning or do you know a better way to change the data source?

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow ? In earlier versions this message was harmless and impossible to get rid of, but it may possibly be fixed in head

Comment: I'm using 0.8.0, not sure if that is considered old.

Comment: The changes I'm thinking about are in a later version (compiled from head)

Answer (score 0):

As Yaroslav said; I believe this warning is fixed in more recent versions of TF.